# How to disable anonymous access to MongoDB and grant asscess only to specific database

Tags: mongodb

I need to disable anonymous access to my MongoDb Server and grant access only to specific database

My steps:

1. I have created TestDB database in MongoDB
2. I have created TestAdmin user in this database
3. I have restarted my MongoDB server with --auth parameter

TestAdmin has **dbAdmin** role

I expected than I could access TestDB database via TestAdmin with its password

> mongo.exe localhost:27017/TestDB -u TestAdmin -p TestAdmin

But I get

> Error 18 authentication failed

Where is a mistake?

Comment: mongo.exe localhost:27017/TestDB -u TestAdmin -p TestAdmin

Comment: Same result. Also I tried to get access by RoboMongo GUI app using authorization tab